# Database transactions theory

Tags: sql, database, transactions

No book seems to be able to answer this.

Suppose I have two transactions:

T1: Lock A, Lock B, Unlock A

T2: Lock B, Unlock B, Lock A, Unlock A

Q1. How many ways are there to plan these transactions? (Is it just a simple graph and the result is 3! * 4! ?)

Q2. How many of these ways are serializable?

I would really like to know what is the thinking process, how do you get to the answer?

Comment: I would take the factorial approach as well.  I marked your question as a favorite and upvoted because is a great question and I would like to know myself

Answer (score 0):

Q1 is 7.
Proof: First of all, we have to merge the set 'Lock A', 'Lock B', 'Unlock A' (I denote the items as A1, A2, A3) into the set 'Lock B',..,'Unlock A' (I denote them B1..B4), that is to put 3 items into 5 places (between B's) with repetitions allowed, that is binomial coeff. choose 3 from (5-1+3). It is equal to 7!/(3!*4!) = 35.
Next, we have to drop 'bad' solutions (the ones prevented by locking conditions). It's where A1 stands between B3 and B4 (3 solutions) and A2 between B1 and B2 (2*4 = 8).  Also, we have to exclude the solutions with B3 between A1 and A3 too. There are 3*3=9 with B3 between A1 and A2, and 6*2=12 with B3 between A2 and A3.  Thus, we have 35-3-8-9-12=3. But we should also satisfy inclusion-exclusion principle: add solutions which violates two rules simultaneously. They could be only like this: B1 A2 B2 B3 B4, with A1 in either of two left positions, and A3 in either of two right ones. 4 in total.  So, we have the final answer 35 - 3 - 8 - 9 - 12 + 4 = 7.

Comment: Q2. What does 'serializable' mean precisely?